# How long do temporary files made with mktemp last?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

I was wondering how long temp files created with mktemp last. It seems strange to me to rely on a file that could disappear at any time. I'm on ubuntu, if it matters.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Huh? From `man mktemp`:

```
DESCRIPTION
   Create  a  temporary  file  or directory, safely, and
   print its name.  TEMPLATE must  contain  at  least  3
   consecutive  `X's  in last component.  If TEMPLATE is
   not specified, use tmp.XXXXXXXXXX,  and  --tmpdir  is
   implied.   Files  are  created  u+rw, and directories
   u+rwx, minus umask restrictions.
```

`mktemp` just adds a random string to create a unique file name. Nobody is going to remove it automatically.

---

Since there seems to be a bit of an argument, lets go into some more detail. `mktemp`'s man page states that

> if TEMPLATE is not specified, `--tmpdir` is assumed, if `--tmpdir` is not specified, `/tmp` is assumed.

This means that simply running `mktemp` will create a file called `tmp.RANDOM_STRING` **in the /tmp directory**. So yes, running `mktemp` with no parameters will create a file that will be cleared along with everything else in `/tmp` in a system-dependent manner. For such files, the `$TMPTIME` variable will be important as explained in Chris's answer below. For many distributions, the default is clearing `/tmp` every boot because `$TMPTIME` is set to `0`. In most (if not all) distributions, this is set in the file `/etc/default/rcS`:

```
$ grep TMPTIME /etc/default/rcS
TMPTIME=0
```

Now, if you *do* specify a TEMPLATE, for example `mktemp fooXXX` then a file called `fooXXX` is created in the current directory where `XXX` is replaced by three random characters. **This file will never be deleted unless you specifically chose to do so.** Only files in the "official" temporary directories such as `/tmp` are ever automatically deleted by the system, there is no magic bit you can set that specifies a temprary file, files outside `/tmp` and its ilk are not deleted automatically.

To answer your main question, of course it is strange to depend on a file that can disappear, that's why people do not depend on tmp files, they are created to temporarily hold data and we can then forget about them. There are many ways of creating a persistent, randomly named file. For example:

```
echo "foo" > $RANDOM.txt
echo "foo" > `mktemp fooXXX.txt`
echo "foo" > $$.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. It says it makes a "temporary" file, and gives no information on how long it lasts. So it lasts forever? Does the tmp directory get perged on system boot?

Comment: @Maksim see updated answer. Also, your question did not ask when the `tmp` directory is cleared but when files created with `mktemp` are deleted. As you can see, the two are not necessarily related :).

Answer (score 8):

Please remember that temp files might be removed during system bootup or as per TMPTIME. Please see what you have in `/etc/cron.daily/tmpwatch`.

`/var/tmp/` on the other hand is immune usually to `tmpwatch`.

Temp files are created for (usually) short period of time. They have temp name so it's not easy to execute timing attack and usually they are deleted when not needed by program anymore. Usually your script would keep this file for very short period of time, usually processing some text or other files and it would remove it as soon as it's not needed. If your script would crash then you would have also fall-back on /tmp folder housekeeping procedures (if that's where you have decided to put them).

You don't have to create temp file in `/tmp`

Comment: Seeing as `mktemp` can be run in any directory and simply produces an arbitrary file name, I don't see how this has anything whatsoever to do with `tmpwatch`.

Comment: By default `mktemp` creates files in `/tmp/`.

Comment: only if you do not give a TEMPLATE, see my updated answer.

Comment: Remove during system bootup.. That is so scary because I only reboot my server once a year ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Temp files do not go away on their own. They are called temp files simply because in your script or session or wherever you are making them, you are expected to delete them when you are done. Or leave them laying around if that's your thing. mktemp exists solely to allow you to come up with a file that is named something unique so that it doesn't overwrite some existing file.

Comment: Don't some systems use a `TMPTIME`?

Comment: @demure yes but only to clear `/tmp` or other tmp directories. It won't just randomly delete user-created files.

Comment: By default `mktemp` creates files in `/tmp/`.